# How do I restore system with backups not timeshift?

Tags: networking, backup, restore

I updated to the new version recently. Now I have no internet connections appearing (with Ethernet connected). And I am looking for a solution that uses the “backups” application. As I assumed that I’d be able to restore my system using it. However now that I have had this problem. Everywhere that I look for a solution suggests using “TimeShift”. As I do not have internet I am unable to do this.

I attempted using “Backups” by launching it and restoring from a version earlier the week by selecting all folders to revert to. But the application crashes when ask to do so.

Need help desperately as lots of modifications have been made and I don’t want to reinstall from the beginning. All information suggested is valued in advance.

Comment: Like I said, I used only “backups” or deja dup to make system snapshots of my progress so far. I would like to restore from one of my previous versions before I updated as it was working fine before it. But when I open that program and select all the folders to revert to. “Backups” crashes, then proceeds to not do anything. The only tutorials online show how to revert small files. Not the entire system. Or use “Timeshift” which I will use going forward. But isn’t included by default so I didn’t know. Please explain and I will be very grateful!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I do not know you are talking about which new version of an OS or application. But it refers to a system upgrade from one older version, e.g. 20.04 -> 22.04, the Backups or TimeShift doesn't work. Run it on the same OS version when the restoration happened.